# Apache Chainsaw read in user defined properties

Tags: log4j, apache-chainsaw

I'm using the snapshot version of apache chainsaw http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy and I just need to read in a text log file. It works fine when I'm reading in keyword columns ex: LEVEL, MESSAGE ect... but when I want to add in a user defined column, it doesn't work.

To read in the text file, I use TIMESTAMP: LOGGER: LEVEL : MESSAGE : PROP(TIER) as my log format where tier is my user defined property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-specified properties via PROP work fine in general - I'm pretty sure the issue is that the MESSAGE field is not the last field in your log format.

Can you reformat your log format to make MESSAGE the last field?

If you can't, I'd try replacing the MESSAGE entry in your log format with a user-defined property like PROP(TEXT).

Either option may work for you.

Comment: it works when i put message last, however i"m thinking about putting exception as the last one...is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Chainsaw supports parsing Java-formatted stack traces and populates the 'exception' field, so if you're using Java it should 'just work' - it combines any subsequent lines starting with a tab followed by 'at ', and sets that text as the exception field of that same log event.  Outside of that, no..I could add regexp support for matching exception lines if you have something different that's needed.